# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exists() on null in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php:1544

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Just installed Xampp 7.2.4 and I get the following error trying to open the ADMIN for MySQL in xampp Control Panel v3.2.2.  I had that setup on another workstation, same OS (Windows Server 2012 R2) same version of xampp but the error I get make no sens to me...any though? Already compare both install and they look similar.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exists() on null in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php:1544 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php(2477): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->postConnectControl() 
#1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(358): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->connect(257) 
#2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(26): require_once('C:\\xampp\\phpMyA...') 
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line 1544
```

Comment: Same error on my machine. I just installed XAMPP 7.2.4.

Answer (score 25):

I just had the same error after a brute force MySQL shutdown.

After tracking down the error in the code, it turned out that it was the browser cookie which was corrupted, preventing PHPMyAdmin to fetch the databases list.

In Google Chrome, you can flush the cookies by:

1. Browse to your PHPMyAdmin page: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
2. Press the F12 key to open the developer tools
3. In the top menu, go to the "*application*" tab
4. In the left menu, click on the "*clear storage*" option.
5. Click on the "*Clear site data button*".

[image: Flush cookie with Chrome developer tools]

Comment: If you are using XAMPP or WAMP, try deleting content under tmp folder, after following these steps.

Answer (score 5):

Go to xampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/databaseintreface
Open in sublime text go on line 1535 the code is written as 
([zeroconf]==true) change it to ([zeroconf]!= true)...

Comment: Tried your post but no luck...same error...restarted PhPMyAdmin and MySQL..

Comment: It worked for me. I'm not using mysql in Xampp. I have installed MYSQL Server Community Edition. After installing Community edition i got this error. And solved now

Answer (score 2):

I've solved upgrading to the most recent version of Phpmyadmin 4.8.2

Answer (score 1):

in the line 1544 , change "if ($GLOBALS['dblist']->databases->exists('phpmyadmin'))"
for "if ($GLOBALS['dblist']->databases->exists('phpMyAdmin'))".

Comment: Tried it and it failed as well...same error...also changed phpmyadmin to phpMyAdmin on line 1545

Answer (score 0):

You can safely comment lines 1543 to 1547 if you already have the `phpmyadmin` database created, which is the case with XAMPP, and it would work just fine.

```
if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ZeroConf'] == true) {
    if (strlen($GLOBALS['db'])) {
        $cfgRelation = $this->relation->getRelationsParam();
        if (empty($cfgRelation['db'])) {
            $this->relation->fixPmaTables($GLOBALS['db'], false);
        }
    }
    $cfgRelation = $this->relation->getRelationsParam();
    // if (empty($cfgRelation['db'])) {
    //     if ($GLOBALS['dblist']->databases->exists('phpmyadmin')) {
    //         $this->relation->fixPmaTables('phpmyadmin', false);
    //     }
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer enhances the previous answers:

1. Edit *DatabaseInterface.php* file
2. Find the following function: **postConnectControl**
3. Comment the body of the function (View image)
4. Save the file.
5. Optional: Restart Apache HTTP Web Server from **XAMPP**

The function must be similar to this:

```
public function postConnectControl()
    {
        // If Zero configuration mode enabled, check PMA tables in current db.
        // if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ZeroConf'] == true) {
            // if (strlen($GLOBALS['db'])) {
                // $cfgRelation = $this->relation->getRelationsParam();
                // if (empty($cfgRelation['db'])) {
                    // $this->relation->fixPmaTables($GLOBALS['db'], false);
                // }
            // }
            // $cfgRelation = $this->relation->getRelationsParam();
            // if (empty($cfgRelation['db'])) {
                // if ($GLOBALS['dblist']->databases->exists('phpmyadmin')) {
                    // $this->relation->fixPmaTables('phpmyadmin', false);
                // }
            // }
        // }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an Android Studio IDE. Which needs PHP My Admin as Database. Once you connect your database into your application. It will mess up your PHP My Admin. Try to close the application first then restart your XAMPP Application. Hope it helps!